# How to add plugin to WordPress Repository?

Tags: plugin-repository, customization

I just made my first plugin and it got approved by WordPress. Great news for me, but now what? The "instructions" on the Codex are anything but clear for me. I did find an article on [Dig WP](http://digwp.com/2010/03/add-plugin-to-wordpress-plugin-repository/) and I managed to get to the 3rd line of code. After that no joy.

Does anyone here have a clear set of instructions on how to do this without the need to read an entire book? I am sure that there are very experienced people here who do this stuff all the time...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try this: http://www.digimantra.com/tutorials/wordpress/publish-wordpress-plugin-on-windows/ this: http://1manfactory.com/wordpress-plugins-upload-with-subversion-tortoise-and-windows-tutorial/

Comment: @Piet: If the links Bainternet mentions in his answer below don't answer your question, we'll need to know what OS & svn tools you are using.

Comment: yup sorry, I should have mentioned that I am on OSX 10.6 (Mac). Also, it's very kind to guide me through the steps of how to write the readme.txt file, but not necessary as the plugin is already approved by WordPress.org. Now I was under the assumption that it can only be approved if the readme.txt file validates, which by the way it does :)

Comment: and I downloaded SVN from the official site (?) but I don't have a clue how it works and what I should do with it. As I mentioned, I followed the tutorial on DIG WP and managed to get the first 3 lines done, before the program halted on me ($ mkdir my-local-dir
$ svn co http://svn.wp-plugins.org/your-plugin-name my-local-dir
$ cd my-local-dir/)

Comment: Actually, application has nothing to do with the readme file. I often apply (and get approved) before I even start development on a plugin.

Comment: @EAMann ok, sorry I didn't know that. Well if all else fails I will start up my old windows laptop to get that plugin uploaded with your instructions, but ideally I would like to learn a Mac solution as that laptop won't live forever...

Comment: managed with @EAMann's instructions. plugin available at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-dashboard-feed-widget/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Step 1 - Make sure things are formatted correctly

WordPress itself depends on the headers at the top of your main plugin file.  In many cases, if your plugin is "My Cool Plugin" this file is `my-cool-plugin.php` in the main directory of your folder.  Make sure the top part of the file follows this format:

```
<?php
/*
=== [Plugin Name] ===

Plugin Name: [Plugin name]
Plugin URI: [Website where plugin information can be found - your blog, maybe]
Description: [Short description of your plugin]
Author URI: [Your website]
Author: [Your name]
Version: [This version number]
*/
```

The WordPress.org repository depends on your `readme.txt` file to create a description and download page.  So make sure your `readme.txt` file fits the following format:

```
=== [Plugin Name] ===
Contributors: [Your WordPress.org username]
Donate link: [A site people can go to to give you money]
Tags: [Search terms related to your plugin]
Requires at least: [Minimum version of WordPress required]
Tested up to: [Newest version of WordPress you've tested with]
Stable tag: [This version number]

[Short, one-sentence description of your plugin]

== Description ==

[Long description of your plugin]

== Installation ==

[Steps required to install the plugin]

== Frequently Asked Questions ==

= [A question] =

[An answer]

= [Another question] =

[Another answer]

== Screenshots ==

== Changelog ==

== Upgrade Notice ==
```

There's a handy [readme validator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/validator/) on WordPress.org you can use to make sure your readme has everything it needs.  Just copy-paste and it will check to make sure all the sections are there and that you're ready to go.

## Step 2 - Check out the SVN repository

It's a good idea to keep your development version separate from the WordPress.org plugin repository.  Yes, SVN is used for version control, but WordPress uses it more for release management.  If you start committing every changeset to the repository, you'll potentially run into problems.  One thing a lot of developers do is develop locally using Git, then transfer your files into the Subversion repository when you're ready to do a release.

> *These instructions assume you're using a Windows computer. If you're on a Mac, you can use [SCPlugin](http://scplugin.tigris.org/) instead of TortoiseSVN.  The steps you'll need to follow will be the same, only the contextual menus and screenshots will differ slightly because of the UI.  I don't have a Mac, so I can't create screenshots to walk you through a tutorial ... but trust me, it's the same process.*

### Install TortoiseSVN if you don't have it already.

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) is an open source Subversion GUI for Windows.  Trust me, using the GUI is infinitely easier than trying to do things from the command line.  You'll run into fewer problems, too.

### Check out your WordPress-hosted SVN repository

Find a place where you want to store the WordPress-hosted version of your plugin.  By default, I use `/My Documents/WordPress/` for all of my hosted dev work.  Right-click inside the folder, and select "SVN Checkout" from the dropdown menu.

[image: TortoiseSVN Contextual Menu]

In the dialog window that pops up, enter your WordPress.org plugin repository URL (I'm using one of mine for demonstration purposes) and choose which subfolder you want to create.

[image: Checkout Dialog]

Tortoise will think for a bit, then it will pull down the repository from WordPress.org.  The newly created folder will have all the requisite folders already set up for you.  Now you just copy-paste and commit ... one step at a time.

### Copy your latest version into `/tags`

This is where I do things backwards from most tutorials.  Everyone else will tell you to commit `/trunk` first, but remember that WordPress doesn't use anything in `/trunk` except the readme file when looking at plugins.  So if you put your plugin into `/trunk` and lose your network connection (or something else goes wrong) before you commit a tag, you'll have issues.

In the `/tags` folder, create a folder named the same as the version you're releasing for your plugin.  So if you're releasing version 0.1, create a `/tags/0.1` folder.

[image: Repository Tags Folder]

Copy your entire plugin into this folder.

Now right-click inside the folder and select "SVN Commit" from the dropdown menu.

You'll see a window pop up that shows all of your changes (you should see all your new files marked as "non-versioned").

[image: Commit Window]

Check the box next to all of your plugin's files (or click "Select All" to select all of them).

In the box on the top, enter a commit message.  Since you're committing a tag, you should probably use something like:

> Tagging version 0.1 of [My Plugin].

Click OK.

Again, Tortoise will think for a few minutes, then it will ask you for your WordPress username and password in order to commit to the server.  Provide them, wait for things to go through and say "Success," then move on to the next step.

### Copy your latest version into `/trunk`

Now navigate to the `/trunk` folder of the repository and once again copy-paste your plugin to that folder.  Go through the same steps above to select your files and prepare the commit.  But for a message, use something that explains what the new release does:

> Version 0.1 of [My Plugin] - adds support for OpenID.

Once everything goes through, you just have to wait a bit for WordPress.org's servers to catch up.  They can be slower some days than others, but within an hour or so you should see your new release in the repository.

### Updating a plugin to a new version

Once your plugin is in the wild, preparing an update is relatively easy.

First, use the SVN Update command to make sure you have the latest version of the repository.  If you're the only developer, you should already, but it's good practice to update before you commit anyway.

Then go through the process above to create a new sub-folder in `/tags` for your new version.  Say, `/tags/0.2`.  Don't touch the old `/0.1` folder.  It's there for a reason and you'll never touch it again.

Commit your new tag, then go to the `/trunk` folder.  Replace everything in `/trunk` with your new version and commit as above.  Once the servers update, they'll start talking about the new version rather than the old one.

Comment: I prefer to do everything from the trunk, since it allows me to get a nice history of [where every line came from](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.1/wp-includes/admin-bar.php?annotate=blame). With your approach, won't everything look like it appeared at the latest version?

Comment: thanks so much for the detailed instructions @EAMann. Unfortunately I am on Mac, sorry, I should have mentioned that in my question, my bad...

Comment: @Jan That's the reason I keep my *development* repo separate from my *release* repo. I've broken things terribly when using the WP.org repos for active development, so I develop locally with either Git or Hg for full version history, then just copy into the WP Svn repo when I build a release.

Comment: @Piet In that case, look at [SCPlugin](http://scplugin.tigris.org/) for Mac. Instructions will be exactly the same, only the screenshots will differ. It's made by a lot of the same people, so it will function just like Tortoise.

Comment: @EAMann Thanks I am downloading it now, will let you know how it goes...

Comment: don't think it worked... for Windows users your answer will be perfect though, so definately a plus from me

Comment: ok, that was me doing sth wrong, now I can see my files on http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/ Thanks so much @EAMann!

Comment: and you can find it here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-dashboard-feed-widget/

Comment: @EAMann - Should be moved to faq... (+1 btw)

Comment: FWIW I posted a longer tutorial today on my blog explaining how you can use the WP-hosted Subversion repository for actual version control (see Jan's comment above). => http://eam.me/f5

Comment: And please set your plugin screenshot images mime-type correctly :)