# Problems in updating a self-developed plugin

Tags: publish, svn

I have problems in publishing the new version of a plugin I published first 5 months ago. Here is what I have done:

- Developed the new functionality, tested all locally (by uploading the generated zip file from the root folder)
- Copied the whole content to the trunk folder of the Wordpress plugin Subversion directory (checkout location on my computer).
- Committed all content (new and changed) to the trunk.
- Created a new tag by using `svn copy trunk tags/0.9.5` and committed that as well.

I can now see on the plugin website that the new version is available, so the README changes have an effect. However, when I download the zip file, it has the old content. And when I install the plugin from the plugin registry, it tells me afterwards that I have installed version 0.9.4, and a new version is available.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here are the public resources to the case:

- My plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/pgnviewerjs-wp/
- SVN directory: https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/pgnviewerjs-wp/

Comment: 11 views, and 2 downvotes (but only 1 comment). I don't get the message here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem myself. Here are the resources that help in finding the (my) fault:

- [Wordpress@Stackoverflow: Update Plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19807/what-is-the-correct-way-to-update-a-plugin-via-tortoise-svn-to-the-repository?rq=1) Detailed description, that explained the same as above in my workflow.
- [Expanded version of the above](https://ttmm.io/tech/how-to-publish-a-wordpress-plugin-subversion/)
- [Wordpress Documentation: Header information in readme.txt](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-your-readme-txt-works/#readme%c2%a0header-information) This was the final point.

I had in my `readme.txt` in the header:

```
Stable tag: /trunk
```

(which possibly never worked correct). I have changed that to

```
Stable tag: 0.9.5
```

I now see on https://wordpress.org/plugins/pgnviewerjs-wp/#description the download button with the link https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/pgnviewerjs-wp.0.9.5.zip which shows me that the version is now available.

So the summary is: Use real version numbers in your readme.txt file!

Comment: and the better answer is to just ask the repository support for ... support

Comment: A quick search for wordpress repository support gives nothing. For anyone not developing plugins dayin - dayout, where would I find that? So that I don't ask silly questions here :-)